# How would I find the SSID of a network in Python 3?

Tags: python, network-programming

Is there a way that Python 3 can tell me about network state of my machine? Specifically:

- The SSID that my machine is currently connected to.
- Internet connectivity state
- Uptime/Downtime

Most important for my use case is the SSID, but the others are nice to have too.

I've seen implementations online that run external programs, and I've seen the [`netifaces`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) package, but it doesn't seem to be able to query the SSID.

Comment: There is not currently any OS independent way to do that. The closest I can find is [the wireless module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wireless/0.3.0) but that doesn't include Windows variants. You can write one, or you can use an OS dependent way.