# How do I get my own SSID using the socket module in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, ssid

I am trying to get the SSID of the WiFi network I am connected to in Python using the socket module. It's probably dead simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my code so far:

```
import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname()
IPAddress = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
print("SSIP: " + hostname)
print("IP-Adress: " + IPAddress)
```

Comment: But the hostname is not the name of the SSIP. It seems that socket doesn't offer a specific get-function for that.

Comment: Naoh Broyles, yes I want to get the name of the wifi network I'm connected too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Python to know what Wifi the user is connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227160/how-do-i-get-python-to-know-what-wifi-the-user-is-connected-to)

Comment: If not, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706483/how-would-i-find-the-ssid-of-a-network-in-python-3

Comment: mkrieger1, I'm aware of the solution using the subprocess-module, but I want to use the socket-module.

Comment: I don't think the socket knows anything about SSIDs.

Comment: A socket is a generic interface to *any kind of network whatsoever*, the majority of which have no concept of anything resembling a SSID.  The `socket` module is not the right place to look for a solution here.

Comment: So there is no possibility using socket ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do :

```
import os
ssid=os.popen("sudo iwgetid -r").read()
```